# Run GUI application via cronjob in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, graphical-user-interface

I have a remote server running "Ubuntu 10.04 Desktop". From it I want to run a script that walks through a list of websites and captures screenshots of them.

The script is working and thoroughly tested.

When I SSH to the server with `ssh -X user@ip-adress` I can run my script by calling `./myscript.py` and everything will work OK.

I then modifed my crontab file and added...
`59 17 * * * env DISPLAY=:0 /path/to/myscript.py`
...as recommended by the Ubuntu WIKI.

I can see in the `/var/log/syslog` that my cron job is started, but it doesn't capture any screenshots.

When running `env DISPLAY=:0 /path/to/myscript.py` from the shell I get
`No protocol specified`
`myscript.py: cannot connect to X server :0`

If I ssh to the server without the `-X` option I only get the second row of the error: `myscript.py: cannot connect to X server :0`

What can I try now?

**More details**

- I have run `xhost +local:` and checked the output of `xhost` to see that the option was set correctly.
- If I run `ls /tmp/.X11-unix/` the output is `X0`
- The server only has one screen.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider running [xvfb](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/xvfb) headless X server.

Comment: This works perfectly fine via SSH (without the `-X` option) but not via Cron.

Comment: I was to quick... Misspelling :) It works perfect!

Comment: excellent... i would still consider setting cron on your workstation, instead of using it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

are you running the script via cron on the server?

also, it will not be :0 when you are doing X over ssh, it is going to be something completely different.

this would be much easier to do locally, or at least kick off locally from cron on the machine you have X running on.

when you log in, and can successfully kick off the script on the server, try `echo $DISPLAY` to see what it is set as. my `sshd_config` has `X11DisplayOffset 10`, which means it would be `hostname:10.0`

Comment: Yes, I run the cron on the server.

I do not have access to this computer physically, just by SSH. Does it really make a difference if the user I ssh with is the same as the main user for the desktop machine?

Comment: username should be insignificant. but running a gui from cron on a machine that you may not always be connected to seems backwards. i would want to launch the script from my computer, when it's on/connected. just something like `* * * * * ssh username@hostname -X -c "/path/to/script.py"` would be preferable, in your workstation's crontab

Comment: I made it work with `xvfb-run /path/to/myscript.py` :) As I said, the script captures screenshots of a list of websites, that's why I need X.

Comment: i'm not saying you don't need X, i just think it would work better, launched from your computer, rather than on the server, because you may not be connected at all times, etc.

Comment: nevermind, it seems you don't even need to do it over ssh anymore, if i'm correct? since you don't need to display anything, `xvfb` is perfect for this, and cron can remain on the server with no problem...